# Synthesis of a bicyclo[2.2.2]octane from benzoic acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

[image]

I think that it is a Diels Alder reaction, but I don't recognize the start materials!
First I make the tertiary alcohol from carboxylic acid with organo-lithium reagent; after I try to make a Diels Alder reaction, but I don't find the right conjugated diene and dienophile.

Answer (score 1):

Supposed that the synthesis does involve a Diels-Alder reaction, it is nowhere written that it is the **last** step in the sequence.

Take another look at your product and imagine a $\ce{C=C}$ double bond somewhere. Does it now look more like a Diels-Alder product? The $\ce{C=C}$ can be turned to $\ce{C-C}$ using... (You figure that out).

Work your path back from here and try to identify diene and dienophile.

---

Don't look until you've figured out the diene ;)

> Convert acid to ester, 2 x $\ce{MeMgBr}$, Diels-Alder reaction with vinylmethyl ether, hydrogenate double bond. You didn't cheat, did you? ;)

Comment: The vinyl ether reacts with the aromatic alcohol by way of a stereospecific Diels-Alder?  Isn't a Birch reduction and subsequent isomerization required?

Comment: Also, it's probably better to keep the ester intact for an inverse electron demand Diels-Alder with vinyl methyl ether.

Comment: @ron Sssssssh, there wouldn't be a diene otherwise ;) But this wasn't your or my homework assignment.

Comment: @KlausWarzecha thank you so much for the clue! I swear that I don't look your complete answer. I think that my dienophile is the aromatic ring, so first I reduct it with Birch reduction. But which is my diene?